# Private repository archive(tar.gz) from GitLab, downloaded using PHP via GitLab's API, appears to be corruputed - invalid checksum

Tags: php, curl, gitlab

I want to download a private GitLab repository archive using their API. I'm using PHP and cURL to do that. I'm able to do so using the following code:

```
$ch = curl_init(http://example.com/api/v3/projects/64/repository/archive?private_token=private_token_goes_here);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_BINARYTRANSFER, true);

$output = curl_exec($ch);
$fh = fopen("out.tar.gz", 'w');
fwrite($fh, $output);
fclose($fh);
```

The code itself is nothing complicated and pretty standard.

The issue I'm facing is that once I try to unpack, using the code bellow:

```
    // decompress from gz
    $p = new PharData($temp_archive . '.tar.gz');
    $p->decompress($temp_archive . '.tar');

    // unarchive from the tar
    $phar = new PharData($temp_archive . '.tar');
    $phar->extractTo($extract_path);
```

I receive the following error:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'UnexpectedValueException' with message ' in phpfile.php on line 294

UnexpectedValueException: phar error: "path/to/downloaded/archive/temp_archive.tar.gz" is a corrupted tar file (checksum mismatch of file "52 comment=01607149cd460cba6f1ac3003bb7b0c9cb0e2b94
") in phpfile.php on line 294
```

Yes, that is the whole error, I didn't cut out the error message. The `'` is the error message.

The checksum for the downloaded file is, indeed, invalid. After a few good hours of Googling and forum browsing I'm back to square one. I have no idea what's wrong with it.

If I was to untar the archive using a terminal(I'm on MAC OS Build 12E55), it will unpack normally. The files are all there and I receive no errors what-so-ever.

I tried manually downloading the archive from GitLab and unpacking it using PHP(I get the same error).

I tried creating a *.tar.gz file using a terminal and unpacking it using PHP(I receive no errors and the unpacking proceeds normally).

I tried uploading a file created using the terminal and downloading it using PHP, after which I unpacked it, again using PHP, and I receive no errors.

I can only assume that I'm either:

- Not using their API properly
- Not setting the right headers - although I had tried setting:

  1. Content-Type: application/octet-stream
  2. Content-Type: application/x-tar
  3. Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary...and so on. When using the binary header, the file that I put the content in was set to `'wb'`. Still, no luck.

And lastly it could be that their API may not be working properly, although I doubt it.

And nudging in the right direction is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This appears to be a bug in the `PharData` class implementation that was fixed only very recently, see https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=64343.

So it seems that Github uses the `pax` format for tar files, instead of the `ustar` format. For a description on `tar` formats, see: https://github.com/libarchive/libarchive/wiki/FormatTar

Comment: Ok, so what are my options here? I'm using `Current PHP version: 5.5.9-1ubuntu4.7`. From the error message I got, which is exactly the same as the one posted in your bug link, it seems that it wasn't properly fixed(?). mike@php.net says it should be `Fixed in d380d1cb1ba48c41682f749692b78a10e91dd070 (5.5.24+).` I'm using GitLab, not Hub, but I assume they're using the same code base.

Comment: upgrade to 5.5.24, use `system` calls or use Pear's `Archive_Tar `

Comment: I'm using 5.5.9, as I said above. Stupid question, is Archive_Tar included by default in PHP or do I need to install it?

Comment: 5.5.24 > 5.5.9, docs on PEAR's Archive_Tar and installation are here: https://pear.php.net/package/Archive_Tar

Comment: 5.5.24 > 5.5.9. How the...you know what, since the next version of PHP is 7, I shouldn't be surprised. I'll look over it, thanks a bunch.

Comment: @Andrew: PHP 7 (skipping PHP 6) is because of different reason (and not marketing black magic at all), You can relate to PHP 5.5.X revision numbers in just the natural and stable (and intutitive) way.